# How do I remove the line if draw the new line

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi everyone please anyone to solve the issues I can draw the line on `UIImageView` but I need to remove the existing line if draw the new line...

```
if(selectBtnTag.tag==111)
    {
            [self selectedButtonBg:selectBtnTag];
               // [self selectBtncolor_Action:@"111" :self.btn_wagonwheel :0];
                //[self.img_pichmap setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"WagonWheel_img"]];
                 _View_Appeal.hidden=YES;
          _view_Wagon_wheel.hidden=NO;



        _View_Appeal.hidden=YES;
        self.view_bowlType.hidden = YES;
        self.view_fastBowl.hidden = YES;
        self.view_aggressiveShot.hidden = YES;
        self.view_defensive.hidden = YES;
        self.img_pichmap.hidden=YES;
        self.PichMapTittle.hidden=YES;

        if(IS_IPAD_PRO)
        {
            self.height.constant=450;
            self.width.constant=450;
        }
        else{
            self.height.constant=350;
            self.width.constant=350;
        }

        if([self.BatmenStyle isEqualToString:@"MSC012"])
        {
            [self.img_WagonWheel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LHWagon"]];
        }
        else{
            [self.img_WagonWheel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RHWagon"]];
        }

        if (IS_IPAD_PRO) {
                    self.centerlbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.img_WagonWheel.frame.size.width/2+46, self.img_WagonWheel.frame.size.width/2+11, 5, 5)];
        }
        else

        self.centerlbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.img_WagonWheel.frame.size.width/2-3, self.img_WagonWheel.frame.size.width/2-30, 5, 5)];

        [self.centerlbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.img_WagonWheel addSubview:self.centerlbl];

        UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didClickWagonWheelmapTapAction:)];
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
        tapRecognizer.delegate=self;
        [self.view_DrawlineWagon addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
        [self.view_DrawlineWagon setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                self.view_bowlType.hidden = YES;
                self.view_fastBowl.hidden = YES;
                self.view_aggressiveShot.hidden = YES;
                self.view_defensive.hidden = YES;


    }
}




-(void)didClickWagonWheelmapTapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)wagon_Wheelgesture
{
    CGPoint p = [wagon_Wheelgesture locationInView:self.img_WagonWheel];
    float Xposition = p.x;
    float Yposition = p.y;
    CGMutablePathRef straightLinePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(straightLinePath, NULL, Xposition, Yposition);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(straightLinePath, NULL,self.centerlbl.center.x,self.centerlbl.center.y);

//    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),self.backgroundColor.CGColor);
//    
//    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);


    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = straightLinePath;
    UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor;
    UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleNonZero;


    [self.img_WagonWheel.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];


}
```

[image]

You can see my images here I can draw the multiple lines but I need to draw the single line if I am drawing the new line, the existing line need to remove please any one help me to solve this issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove the exiting line using this [self.shapeLayer removeFromSuperlayer]; and create a new line

Comment: you are not type SMS so avoid use u plz and all the sort word

Comment: k fine i ll follow here after

Comment: hi Hari can u tell me where should i implement the code

Comment: @fathima you need to remove your shape layer in gesture state if(wagon_Wheelgesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            [self.shapeLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        } in your didClickWagonWheelmapTapAction gesture event

Comment: mr rohit..no its not working can u give me the code where should i implement..how do i do that

Comment: You need to implement touchesBegan event for remove your shape layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `UIGestureRecognizer` method like this

```
-(void)didClickWagonWheelmapTapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)wagon_Wheelgesture {

    for (CALayer *layer in self.img_WagonWheel.layer.sublayers) {
        if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"DrawLine"]) {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
            break;
        }
    }
    CGPoint p = [recognizer locationInView:self.imgDraw];
    float Xposition = p.x;
    float Yposition = p.y;
    CGMutablePathRef straightLinePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(straightLinePath, NULL, Xposition, Yposition);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(straightLinePath, NULL,self.view.center.x,self.view.center.y);
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = straightLinePath;
    UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor;
    UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleNonZero;
    shapeLayer.name = @"DrawLine";
    [self.imgDraw.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: if i draw another line ...the existing should be remove but if i touch continuesly existing draw line also visible

Comment: @fathima i have edited the answer check that. It is working from my side

Comment: -(void)didClickWagonWheelmapTapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)wagon_Wheelgesture {
    for (CALayer *layer in self.img_WagonWheel.layer.sublayers) {
        if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"DrawLine"]) {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
            break;
        }
    }

Comment: CGPoint p = [wagon_Wheelgesture locationInView:self.img_WagonWheel];
    float Xposition = p.x;
    float Yposition = p.y;
    CGMutablePathRef straightLinePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(straightLinePath, NULL, Xposition, Yposition);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(straightLinePath, NULL,self.centerlbl.center.x,self.centerlbl.center.y);

Comment: CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = straightLinePath;
    UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor;
    UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleNonZero;

Comment: after that i follow the line u can see my comments its not working

Comment: [self.img_WagonWheel.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

Comment: @fathima Replace your whole function with my one. I have added all your code with my one. Please replace with my one.

Comment: another doubt how do find the centre position x and  y values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115173/discussion-between-nirav-doctorwala-and-fathima).

Comment: placing the line on centre in wagon wheel